# What the best way to make a CSS class specific?

Tags: css

I could make my css style specific by writing

html:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="foo">
<div class="a2">
  <div class="b2">
    <div class="foo">
<div class="a3">
  <div class="b3">
    <div class="foo">
<!--many more-->
```

and css:

```
.a .b .foo { /*my style*/ }
```

**or**

html:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="foo specific-foo">
<div class="a2">
  <div class="b2">
    <div class="foo">
<div class="a3">
  <div class="b3">
    <div class="foo">
<!--many more-->
```

css:

```
.specific-foo { /*my style*/ }
```

Is there a recommendation for which is better?

**--update**

Can't use id, because I use JSF, which will generate prefixes numbers to the ids.

Comment: Why not just use `.c { /* your style */}` ?

Comment: Better? Better how? The structure is identical between your examples but the selectors are different.

Comment: @web-tiki because there will be another c in another part of the code. I need to make it specific.

Comment: @TomBrito well there is no "recomendation" or "better" approach for this. choose the simplest for you to write, remember and maintain.

Comment: You're targeting the same element either way. The only time specificity comes into play is if there are other rules that apply to that element, and without knowing if there are, and how specific they are, there's not much to say.

Comment: @TomBrito In my opinion also after your new edit, you should always try to be as generic and descriptive as possible. Avoid writing specific classes. If it is specific, use a specific nested way to format it

Comment: I would disagree this question will only result in an opinion based answer. It's a bad practice to increase specificity of your CSS using multiple selectors as it makes your CSS less maintainable and difficult to override using the natural cascade. Coupling your CSS styles to the DOM structure is generally a bad idea. If you wish to move `.a .b. foo` to somewhere else in the DOM you have to change your CSS. If you style using `.specific-foo`, you can change your DOM without affecting styles. This is in the general spirit of BEM and other CSS methodologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.specific-c` is *specific* only for this element, therefore you should not give it a new class.

**Format it in a nested way.**

As [W3C](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames) describes:

> Use `class` with semantics in mind.

`.container`, `.navbar`, `.btn-info` are good names. They are ***reusable*** and ***descriptive***.

`.title-in-news-section` is not.

If `.specific-c` situation reoccurs one day in more places than you expected, give it its own class or divide it to a couple of generic classes.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a great example. [All their class names](https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145) are semantic and generic, what makes them so powerful and easy to use.

Comment: Really, I should rather use an id, instead of `.specific-c`.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS ids, ids are made to be specific **to one div** and classes **multiple.**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div id="c>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a {} .b{} #c{}
```

You can read more about the ID selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp).

**EDIT:**

Considering you *can't* use IDs, there are still other CSS selectors to consider:

Using the `>` selecetor specifically identifies parent and child relationships.

In the following example, you are selecting c that is the child of b, that is the child of a, giving your CSS more specific definition and makes your code unique.

`.a > .b > .c`

Otherwise using classes are acceptable and still valid, but makes it difficult when you start coding class after class after class...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I can't use ids. I updated the question.

Comment: @TomBrito I added an edited section to my answer but kept the ID information considering someone else might have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Use ID to have unique selector.

If that is not an option, than specify selector like

```
.a > .b > .c
```

*Is there a recommendation for which is better?* - No, it depends on your needs and structure

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I can't use ids. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the second approach is preferable - the first one will also apply mistakenly to the c in:

```
<div class="a">
<div class="foo"> 
<div class="b">
<div class="bar">
<div class="c">
```

You can also do what Shaun Loftin suggests, and modify the first case to be:

```
.a > .b > .c
```

Modified that way, `.a > .b > .c` is preferable, because that way, you do not need the additional css class (`specific-c`). The less classes, the better, in general.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this is down to personal preference.

For me personally, I go with being as **specific** as I need to be. For example:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I wanted to style `.c` and make the font color red, I'd simply declare

```
.c {
    color: red;
}
```

However, further down the line there may be a style that overrides that, such as:

```
.a .c {
    color: green;
}
```

In this case, I'll need to override the `.a .c {}` declaration. I could do this in a number of ways, however the following will suffice:

```
.b > .c {
    color: red;
}
```

If I wanted to override that again in the future, I can use `.a > .b > .c {}`

There's no point in writing a really really specific class declaration just for the sake of it, as you won't be able to override it unless you go even more specific, or use the dreaded `!important` - **AVOID** using `!important` unless it's absolutely crucial or you have a valid reason.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67pnbnxf/1/